# CheckStyle doesnt work for me

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I am trying to run CheckStyle 5.6 with Eclipse 4.2.1. but unable to do so.

Then i Saved the Sun Checks (Eclipse) with myConfig
[image]

Then I modified the properties as below , making empty block and need braces at error level in new config

Now in Code i have code like

```
if(true){}
```

When i save java file i was expecting it to show as error in "checkstyle violations" view

Check Styles is Enabled it for my project

but didnt get ... what am i doing wrong ??

Comment: I never saw an Anal check before xD

Comment: is checkstyle enabled for your project?

Comment: Have you actually enabled checkstyle for that project ?

Comment: updated question , have checkstyle enabled for that proj ... what else could be wrong ??

Comment: wild guess: maybe Checkstyle doesn't check the source if it doesn't compile. `if() {}` is not valid Java.

Comment: i will try if(true) {} , but i dont think thats the issue , as i tried violating other rules , like exceeding maximum number of lines (made more than 80 chars aprox 120) still i didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "build automatically" is not activated in your Eclipse (in the menus under "Project").

Checkstyle only runs as part of the Build (triggered by the *Checkstyle Builder*).

Comment: i doubt that , will recheck ... whenever i change the checkstyle it asks me this will need an automatic rebuild yes or no ? i choose yes ... moreover i also right click the project and choose "check code with checkstyle" , then also it doesnt work